# Need command to find the dat files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, aix

Can anyone help us in writing a command in shell script to find the files with .dat extension and which are lagging for 60 mins from current time. This script wil schedules to run for every 30mins.

Comment: laggins means the file should be processed automatically, but for some reason it will not process. so i need to send an alert to some team to process the files manually. Suppose, now the time is 10:00 AM and the .dat file time stamp is 8:55 AM. A script is written to find the files with above requirement and it will be scheduled for every half an hour. Please kindly help

Comment: What is the "ais" tag?  The tag wiki is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *"lagging for 60 mins from current time"* means you want to find files that have a modification time of greater than 60 minutes ago:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +60 -name '*.dat'
```

Comment: No it is not working. Maxdepth is not a valid option is result i am getting. The time difference between file changed time and current time should be greater than or equal to 60mins.

Comment: What OS are you using? `uname -a`.  This works for me with GNU `find` on Ubuntu 12.04 and BSD `find` on OSX.

Comment: My operating system is UNIX. Can any other command help us for this requirement.

Comment: Which flavour of UNIX?  BSD?  HP-UX?  Solaris?  OSX?  AIX?  Something else?

Comment: I'm guessing the "ais" tagging is a typo and your using AIX.  Looks like AIX `find` doesn't have that option http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Ffind.htm

Comment: @DigitalTrauma No, it's there. `maxdepth` is not there. `mmin` is available. OP should remove the `maxdepth` and give it a shot. +1 as it is a good working solution atleast for me! `;)`.

Answer (score 0):

#### In a unix system you can use -mtime "hours"

```
find . -name "*.dat" -mtime +1
```